# Convergence of semi-gradient TD(0) with non-linear function approximation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, convergence, function-approximation, temporal-difference-methods, on-policy-methods

I am looking for a result that shows the convergence of semi-gradient TD(0) algorithm with non-linear function approximation for on-policy prediction. Specifically, the update equation is given by (borrowing notation from Sutton and Barto (2018))

$$\mathbf w \leftarrow \mathbf w +\alpha [R + \gamma \hat v(S', \mathbf w) - \hat v(S, \mathbf w)] \nabla \hat v(S, \mathbf w)$$

where $\hat v(S, \mathbf w)$ is the approximate value function parameterized by $\mathbf w$.

Sutton and Barto (2018) mention that the above update equation converges when $\hat v$ is linear in $\mathbf w$. But I couldn't find a similar result for non-linear function approximation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is an example of non-convergence for semi-gradient sarsa, [according to Rich Sutton](https://media.nips.cc/Conferences/2015/tutorialslides/SuttonIntroRL-nips-2015-tutorial.pdf) (check slide 35). I guess TD(0) is not so different. So, probably your approximator will need to satisfy certain conditions to proof convergence.

Maybe [this paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SJezGp4YPr) will be useful for you. It seems that they show that constraining your network to have relu activation functions allow you to show some convergence properties.